# Passing a CSV file to rspec as a param

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, csv, controller, rspec2

I have the following function in my users_controller to upload a csv file from local disk and export the user details in it into my application. The code is working correctly in the application but I am unsure as to how about passing the csv in the test. My function is as follows:

```
def upload
  if request.post?
    if (params[:user].nil? || params[:user][:csv].blank?)
      flash[:notice] = "Please provide a csv file to upload."; return
    end 

    file = params[:user][:csv].read   
    CSV.parse(file, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol).each { |row| Cortex::User.create(row.to_hash) }

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to admin_engine.cortex_users_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end    
  else
    # Provide upload view
  end     
end
```

Here is my attempt at trying to cover this in the rspec tests.

```
it "should be a success" do
  post "admin/users/upload", :user => @user, :user_csv => fixture_file_upload(Admin::Engine.root.join('spec/dummy/tenants_sample.csv')), :session_token => @auth_token
  response.code.should eq("200")
end
```

When I check the LOC coverage with the coverage gem I can see that the test enters the first two if statements before exiting.

Anyone got any tips on how I could go about passing this file in so that it could then be read by the rest of the function.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, testing CSV composition or parsing doesn't belong in your current test. Ultimately, all such a test will do is test either the CSV module or the validity of your CSV file--which is a brittle test and tells you very little about your application.

A better testing practice would be to perform a test of the *model* to ensure that:

1. A properly-formatted CSV is imported the way you expect.
2. Malformed CSV files are handled appropriately for your application.

The controller should just stub or mock the CSV parsing because it's not relevant to the response code test, and the logic really belongs in the model anyway. YMMV.